# Add Desktop Notifications with Icon and Audio to Meteor Web Application

Tags: javascript, meteor, notifications, html5-audio

I have been trying to add a simple HTML5 desktop notification to my Meteor Web Application. Here is the code,

```
if (!("Notification" in window)) {
        alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
        }

        // Let's check whether notification permissions have already been granted
       else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
            var date = new Date();
            var audio = new Audio();
            audio.src = "../../../universal/bells.wav";
            audio.load();
            audio.play();
            var notification = new Notification("Allow Notifications!", {
                              dir: "auto",
                              lang: "hi",
                              tag: "testTag"+date.getTime(),
                              icon: "../../../assets/notification.png",
                              });
          }

        // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
        else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
          Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
          if (permission === "granted") {
            var notification = new Notification("Granted Permission for Notifications");
          }
      });
      }
```

But both the audio and the image is not getting displayed. 
This is the error message I get for audio files,

"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found."

If I comment out the audio part of the code, the image icon is throwing an error,

"Refused to load the image 'http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/96/139.jpg' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src data: 'self' http://*.googleapis.com https://*.googleapis.com http://*.gstatic.com https://*.gstatic.com http://*.bootstrapcdn.com https://*.bootstrapcdn.com"."

and no image is displayed.

Is there any other way to implement desktop notifications in a Meteor App?
Also, is there a way to make the notification come in the center of the page?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution! All the media has to be in the public folder in meteor to be accessed!